# Progressive load of elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to progressively load items with a short delay between each?

For example, I have 5 elements and I wish to fade them in (using CSS3 transitions and `opacity`) but I wish them to load in one after the other.

Here is a JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ndmbr1wk/

What's the best way to choose each jQuery item and delay the `.css()` function on it by 1 second?

The following code obviously applies the CSS to all `.diamond` items at once, but I am not sure the easiest way to apply this to each item one after the other, without putting in 5 different classnames e.g `.diamond-1`

```
$("p").click(function() {
$('.diamond').each(function() {
  $( this ).delay('1000').css('opacity','1');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Change `css` to `animate`, using `0` as the duration so that it doesn't interfere with the CSS transitions.

You can then use jQuery's **[`delay`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)** function:

```
$('p').click(function() {
  $('.diamond').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).delay(idx*1000).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 0);
  });
}).click();
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/uwav3zzn/2/)

Comment: Thanks, this is a clean solution

Comment: & what about, if one clicks 2nd time?

Comment: @ParkashKumar, OP hasn't stated that anything should happen on a second click.

Comment: I was asking just for my knowledge.

Comment: I'm actually trying to have this act on a scroll past the header. It seems to have real issues. The first box won't load and it doesn't start the animation cleanly when the header is scrolled past. Any ideas? https://jsfiddle.net/uwav3zzn/3/

Comment: @ParkashKumar, the code *will* run on subsequent clicks, but you won't see anything different since `opacity` is already 1.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't use `.css()` if you are using the CSS transition anyway.

Comment: I *think* that using `animate` with `0` duration is identical to using `css`.  It simply gives you the ability to use jQuery's `delay` function.

Comment: @Francesca, `$(window).scroll` runs repeatedly while the window is scrolling.  You probably want to turn off the `scroll` function once the animation begins by using `$(window).off('scroll');`.  See https://jsfiddle.net/v73daopp/

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ndmbr1wk/10/

```
$("p").click(function() {
    $('.diamond').each(function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).addClass("loaded");
        }, index * 1500);
    });        
});
```

Then add a class in CSS:

```
.loaded {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Make sure the timeout equals the `transition-duration` in your CSS if you want to load one after the other.

You could also animate in jQuery as Rick suggests, however by doing so you won't utilise the goodiness of CSS3 (e.g. hardware acceleration). EDIT: he has edited his answer which would now allow for hardware acceleration. By using `animate()` he can use `delay()`, and by setting its animation duration to `0` he's sure that CSS animations (and hardware acceleration) is used. Neat solution!

Comment: & what about, if I click 2nd time?

Comment: @ParkashKumar OP hasn't stated that anything should happen on a second click. ;)

Comment: @BramVanroy, good point about the hardware acceleration.  I've updated my answer to use 0 as the animation duration.